# OMXNodeInstance getParameter(0xXXXXXXX:Exynos.avc.dec, ??(0xXXXXXXXX)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0xXXXXXXXX) when playing videos

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, rendering, android-kernel

Good day devs,

While working on our Android custom kernel, we have met a problem that is when a video is being played, an error under this form appears in logs:

```
getParameter(0xXXXXXXX:Exynos.avc.dec, ??(0xXXXXXXXX)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0xXXXXXXXX)
```

The Xs are some numbers who are various everytime, the problem is always by `OMXNodeInstance` process, it causes video rendering issues, we have no idea of how to solve those video rendering issues.

The kernel is based on the official Samsung kernel for some devices, the processor is Exynos.

the kernel version is 4.4
This is the source link:
https://github.com/eurekadevelopment/Eureka-Kernel-Exynos7885-Q-R-S

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We made a custom kernel, built some custom roms on it, but some users are experiencing video rendering issues while playing video, when referring to logs, the process `OMXNodeInstance` is reporting an error under this form:.                 `getParameter(0xXXXXXXX:Exynos.avc.dec, ??(0xXXXXXXXX)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0xXXXXXXXX)`  and that's the error that is happening while playing videos as i said